# TabBar within Scaffold with my own controller doesn't work

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-navigation

I am using a Scaffold and within the Body I want to use the TabBar Widget, to switch between Info, Adress and Delivery. But with this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lieferantenapp/components/myBestellungText.dart';
import 'package:lieferantenapp/components/myLieferbuttons.dart';
import 'package:lieferantenapp/route/route.dart';
import 'package:lieferantenapp/variables.dart' as variables;

class CurrentDetail extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CurrentDetailState createState() => _CurrentDetailState();
}

class _CurrentDetailState extends State<CurrentDetail>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;
  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = new TabController(
      vsync: this,
      length: 3,
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                MyBestellungText(),
                MyLieferbuttons(),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          TabBar(
            controller: _tabController,
            labelColor: Colors.black,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black12,
            indicatorColor: variables.red,
            tabs: const <Widget>[
              Tab(
                text: "Hey",
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.info_outline,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Hey",
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.info_outline,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                text: "Hey",
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.info_outline,
                  color: Colors.black,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text("Test 1"),
              Text("Test 2"),
              Text("Test 3"),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am receiving the following Error like 10 times.

```
════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#d08ff relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1930 pos 12: 'hasSize'

The relevant error-causing widget was
TabBarView
lib\screens\currentDetail.dart:73
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

I tried using the DefaultTabController within the Scaffold and also tried wrapping the Scaffold in the DefaultTabController, but it didn't recognize it either ways. Right now I am running it with a customized Controller, but I'm not quite sure if this is the best way to do this and it isn't working anyways xD.
How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `TabBarView` with an `Expanded` widget.

```dart
Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
    controller: _tabController,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("Test 1"),
      Text("Test 2"),
      Text("Test 3"),
    ],
  ),
),
```

I would also recommend you to put `TabBar` in the `bottom` property of `AppBar`.

```dart
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    bottom: TabBar(...),
  ),
  ...
),
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Regarding the bottom property. I want dont want the TabBar within the AppBar, I want to have some Text inbetween. Is that possible within the AppBar -> bottom?

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Could you give an example of `Text in-between` thing?